# ¿Cómo utilizar switch case seleccionando input tipo radio?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php7, laravel-7

Tengo lo siguiente dentro de un wizard o step:

```
<p><input type="radio" name="edad" value="uno" /> Producto 1</p>
<p><input type="radio" name="edad" value="dos" /> Producto 2</p>
<p><input type="radio" name="edad" value="tres" /> Producto 3</p>
```

Los dos primeros productos tienen un plan de suscripción iguales en precio, pero el producto 3 tiene un costo más alto. Lo que busco es implementar lo siguiente sin dar click en el submit, se muestre los planes disponibles al seleccionar sea el producto 1 ó 2, ya si selecciona el 3 muestre el caso 2.

```
@switch($i)
@case(1)
     <select name="plan">
     <!-- Opciones de planes -->
     <option value="1">Opción $10</option>
     <option value="2">Opción $20</option>>
     <option value="3">Opción $45</option>
</select>
    @break

@case(2)
    <select name="plan">
     <!-- Opciones de planes -->
     <option value="1">Opción $25</option>
     <option value="2">Opción $40</option>>
     <option value="3">Opción $95</option>
    @break
@endswitch
```

Comment: el wizard es por jquery o por instancias de .blade?

Comment: Por blade no puedes porque tendrias que refrescar la pagina, la unica es por js o mas facil aun por jquery